# Service Discovery in Istio servicemesh

Tags: istio

We currently are using Eureka(API discovery) and Spring cloud gateway for our microservices. We plan to istio installed on to our kubernetes clusters. My question is whether Istio can be used for Service Discovery and we can do away with Eureka and Spring Cloud Gateway?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service discovery part is taken care of by Kubernetes. I'd recommend you check the official documentation for that. See: [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Istio has capabilities of extending the service discovery for mesh workloads with services external to the Kubernetes Cluster (in addition to all the other capabilities it provides for Traffic Management, Observability, and Security)